# How to toggle classes with boolean model property in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried this:

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in todos" class="{{todo.isCompleted ? 'test'}}">
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle"/>
<label>{{todo.text}}</label><button class="destroy"></button>
</li>
```

But then I got an error:

`Error: Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 17-17 [?] in expression [todo.isCompleted ? 'test']`

Comment: Use `ng-class` for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397252/angularjs-toggle-class-using-ng-class?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

Use `ng-class` like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-class="{ 'test' : todo.isCompleted }">
```

[Reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass)

Answer (score 2):

`ng-class="{ 'test' : todo.isCompleted }"`