# Toggle <a> class with Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular.js to create a simple tabbed interface, but I would like to toggle a class of `active` on whichever link I just clicked. Here is my code

```
    <header>
    <nav>
    <a href ng:click="selected=1">Home</a>
    <a href ng:click="selected=2">About</a>
    <a href ng:click="selected=3">Work</a>
    <a href ng:click="selected=4">Blog</a>
    <a href ng:click="selected=5">Login</a>
    </nav>
    </header>

    <article ng:hide="selected == 2 || selected == 3 || selected == 4 || selected == 5" >
    <section>
    <h2>1</h2>
    </section>
    </article>

    <article ng:show="selected == 2">
    <section>
    <h2>2</h2>
    </section>
    </article>


    <article ng:show="selected == 3">
    <section>
    <h2>3</h2>
    </section>
    </article>


    <article ng:show="selected == 4">
    <section>
    <h2>4</h2>
    </section>
    </article>


    <article ng:show="selected == 5">
    <section>
    <h2>5</h2>
    </section>
    </article>
```

[I also made a CodePen](http://codepen.io/AdamBlumMusic/pen/gfuiy). 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to conditionally apply a class with angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class-with-angularjs)

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS toggle class using ng-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397252/angularjs-toggle-class-using-ng-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ng-class` directive:

```
<header>
        <nav>
            <a href ng:click="selected=1" ng-class="{active: selected == 1}">Home</a>
            <a href ng:click="selected=2" ng-class="{active: selected == 2}">About</a>
            <a href ng:click="selected=3" ng-class="{active: selected == 3}">Work</a>
            <a href ng:click="selected=4" ng-class="{active: selected == 4}">Blog</a>
            <a href ng:click="selected=5" ng-class="{active: selected == 5}">Login</a>
        </nav>
</header>
```