# How to apply a class in angular based on a value in the scope?

Tags: angularjs

in angular I have a function that looks like this:

```
$scope.memberselect =function(myname){
    $scope.member = (myname);
 };
```

I try to set a class based on $scope.member. LIke this:

```
 ng-class="{expanded: member = mathieu}"
```

I want the node with the attribute to get the value expanded if $scope.member = mathieu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS toggle class using ng-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397252/angularjs-toggle-class-using-ng-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ng-class="{ 'expanded' : member == 'mathieu' }"
```

or

```
ng-class="{ 'expanded' : true }[member == 'mathieu']"
```