# Applying ng-class based on value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class, angular-ng-if

I have a simple `ng-repeat` that displays a list of scores and a value of either Positive or Negative.

What i am trying to do is when the value is Negative, display a red background CSS class, and when Positive, display a green CSS class. However, for some reason, i am always seeing the **red** CSS class on my page.

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="scores in Test" ng-class="{true: 'warning', false: 'ok'}[scores.Indicator == 'Negative']">                       
     <td>Overall: {{ scores.Indicator }}</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.warning {
    background: red;
}

.ok {
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I haven't seen that particular syntax used before, what's the rationale behind `{true: 'warning', false: 'ok'}[scores.Indicator == 'Negative']`?

The way I would use `ngClass` here is

```
<tr ng-repeat="scores in Test" ng-class="{warning: (scores.Indicator == 'Negative'), ok: (scores.Indicator != 'Negative')}">
```

Does that work?

For better readability you could delegate it to the controller as well

```
<tr ng-repeat="scores in Test" ng-class="scoreClass(scores)">

$scope.scoreClass = function(scores) {
    return scores.Indicator == 'Negative' ? 'warning': 'ok';
}
```

Or you could create a directive

```
<tr ng-repeat="scores in Test" score-class scores="scores">

.directive('scoreClass', [function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            scores: '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.$watch('scores', function() {
                element.removeClass('ok');
                element.removeClass('warning');
                if (scope.scores.Indicator == 'Negative') {
                    element.addClass('warning');
                } else {
                    element.addClass('ok');
                }
            }, true);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: The rational is behind Solution 2 in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397252/angularjs-toggle-class-using-ng-class   Using your answer, my rows are now all green (even for the Negative ones)

Comment: Hmm.. that's interresting, I wonder if your original approach would work with `"{true: 'warning', false: 'ok'}[(scores.Indicator == 'Negative')]`? (e.g wrapping the logical test in the square brackets with parentheses)

Comment: @OamPsy Well, now I'm confused. I pasted your HTML into a plnkr and it worked fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/p5rLB6cjNrTPVkWDnw9A?p=preview

Comment: as mentioned above,  i had a syntax error, your solution works