# Function used inside ng-repeat is being called twice in every iteration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For a setup like this:

## HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data.checkList">                
   <i ng-class="faClass(item.status)">&nbsp;</i>&nbsp;<span>{{item.Name}}</span>
</li>
```

## JS

```
$scope.data.checkList = [
   {'status':'COMPLETED', 'name':'Task 1'},
   {'status':'NOT STARTED', 'name':'Task 2'}
];

$scope.faClass = function(status){
   console.log(status);
};
```

## BROWSER CONSOLE

```
COMPLETED
NOT STARTED
COMPLETED
NOT STARTED
```

Is this behavior expected? How do I solve it and avoid the duplication?

## JSFIDDLE

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/frydnmut/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's normal, basically AngularJS uses **`dirty-checking`** to figure out what (and 
when) to repaint.

**[`How does data binding work in AngularJS?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/how-does-data-binding-work-in-angularjs/9693933#9693933)**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.data ={};
 $scope.data.checkList = [
   {'status':'COMPLETED', 'name':'Task 1'},
   {'status':'NOT STARTED', 'name':'Task 2'}
];

$scope.faClass = function(status){
   console.log(status);
};
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div class="form-group">
  <li ng-repeat="item in data.checkList">                
   <i ng-class="faClass(item.status)">&nbsp;</i>&nbsp;<span>{{item.name}}</span>
</li>
</div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So how I do make sure the function runs only twice?

Comment: what is the need to call function inside ng-repeat

Comment: Based on the status, a number of css classes will be applied to it

Comment: you can conditonally apply css class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762578/applying-ng-class-based-on-value

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior of AngularJS. AngularJS uses a digest cycle to check if there any changes to variables. Therefore, as part of the digest cycle's dirty checking, it will check a few times to ensure there have been no changes to the variable. See more in the 'Scope Life Cycle' section: [$scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

If you want the value to only be bound once you can prepend `::` to your function call. Note: It's still going to be called twice, but it will be called no more than twice using `::`.

```
<i ng-class="::faClass(item.status)">&nbsp;</i>&nbsp;<span>{{item.Name}}</span>
```