# angular leaflet map redraw after parent div width change

Tags: html, css, angularjs, leaflet

I have a leaflet map in a bootstrap div:

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" id="kartencol">
      <leaflet defaults="defaults" center="center" paths="meinePfade" bounds="bounds"     decorations="decorations" width="100%" height="480px" markers="markers"></leaflet>
</div>
```

I use jquery and css animation to change the width of the col div and put a form next to it.

```
$('#kartencol').toggleClass('col-xs-10 col-xs-7')
$('#formcol').toggleClass('col-xs-0 col-xs-3')
```

It works great, but when I do something with the map now like setting bounds, angular does this with the old map width.

How do I do a redraw or anything else with the map, to let angular know about the new width?

Best
Joerg

Comment: For start you should avoid using jQuery inside Angular code. Take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15397408/1418878) how to replace `toggleClass()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by calling the `invalidateSize` function of your `L.Map` instance. When using the angular-leaflet-directive you can get an instance of your map by using `leafletData.getMap` function in your controller:

```
leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
    map.invalidateSize();
});
```

Here's the reference on `invalidateSize`: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-invalidatesize

> Checks if the map container size changed and updates the map if so — call it after you've changed the map size dynamically