# NG-CLASS - If Class Exist on Parent <a>

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-class, ng-show

I am using a offcanvas bootstrap/jasny nav.  What I am trying to do is switch out a class on a icon based upon if the div has the "canvas-slid" on it.  I was wondering if this can be done with NG-CLASS based on if a Class exist on a parent .  Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f3mgacy4/8/ with the code based on jQuery.  the only issue with the jQuery is when you click anywhere it hides the nav, but doesn't change the icon.  So I would like to know if you can do this with NG-CLASS if not how would you do it with jQuery.

```
<a id="filterLink" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-placement="right" data-target=".filter-menu"><span id="filterIcon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter text-white"></span></a>

<div class="offcanvas filter-menu">
    Offcanvas fly in filter...
</div>
```

Comment: It can be done with ng-class: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15397408/2794702

Comment: @Ursus I am new to Angular - can you provide an example.  I tried to change the Plnkr page = failed.

Comment: you want to display an element if parent-element has a class, correct?

Comment: @Ursus Yep - in the fiddle you can see what I am up too.  The jansy bootstrap added a class of canvas-slid when the div flies in.