# AngularJS class toggle on buttons

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to toggle a class when a button is clicked. IE: if button 'rndTotal' is selected, class "selected" is added, and the other buttons have class "selected" removed. I also need this approach to work with my controller, as in, I will have stuff happen based on what is selected.

So far I have:

```
      <div class="row optionRow" ng-init="option = 'exact'" >
        <div class="col">
          <button ng-class="{selected:option=='exact'}">Exact</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button ng-class="{selected:option=='rndTip'}">Round Tip</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button ng-class="{selected:option=='rndTotal'}">Round Total</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

It defaults to 'exact' but doesn't function other than that.

Comment: What is select($index) doing?

Comment: At the moment...nothing. I was trying to figure out what is the best method to then reference in my controller.

Comment: Not answering the question, but [this directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons) does exactly what you need. (If you want to include another dependency in your project, off course).

Comment: you could try replacing select($index) with select('exact') for example, and then have $scope.select assign the argument ('exact') to the variable $scope.option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS toggle class using ng-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397252/angularjs-toggle-class-using-ng-class)

Comment: @GabrielHobold I'd hope there would be a way to handle this with angular without another dependency.

Comment: @gevorg I review this question before posting. It toggles multiple classes at once, I need it to switch between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a hack, but to accomplish what you're after you could do this:

```
<div class="row optionRow" ng-init="option = 'exact'" >
    <div class="col">
        <button ng-class="{selected:option=='exact'}" ng-click="option='exact'">Exact</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <button ng-class="{selected:option=='rndTip'}" ng-click="option='rndTip'">Round Tip</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <button ng-class="{selected:option=='rndTotal'}" ng-click="option='rndTotal'">Round Total</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Instead of setting model values directly in the markup like this, I would move to using a controller. In order to do that I would make the following changes:

*Controller*

```
.controller('myController', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.selectedOption = 'exact';
    vm.selectOption = function(option) {
        vm.selectedOption = option;
        // do anything else you may need to do when the selected option changes
    };
});
```

*Markup*:

```
<div ng-controller="myController as vm">
    <div class="row optionRow">
        <div class="col">
            <button ng-class="{selected:vm.selectedOption==='exact'}" ng-click="vm.selectOption('exact')">Exact</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <button ng-class="{selected:vm.selectedOption==='rndTip'}" ng-click="vm.selectOption('rndTip')">Round Tip</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <button ng-class="{selected:vm.selectedOption==='rndTotal'}" ng-click="vm.selectOption('rndTotal')">Round Total</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. Could you ELI5 why you (1) think it's hacky, and (2) why this solution even works? I am pretty new to Angular so I'm trying to figure out the best way to do things.

Comment: I don't like to set model values directly in the markup like this. I prefer to use the controller for things like this. I'll update my answer with how I would approach this.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you for the explanation and providing your preferred method.

Comment: @nc45 I just realized that I didn't explain why the first answer works. When you use `ng-init="option = 'exact'"` you are implicitly creating a model property named `option`. I took advantage of this and just directly set the value of that model property in the `ng-click` event of each button. Hopefully that makes sense.