# Ng-Class causes two classes to be active when the page first loads

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, font-awesome

I am trying to set a value for an ng-class but when it first loads if the expression evaluates to true then both classes in the ng-class are applied to the tag.
I am using font-awesome and toggling between two icons. Here is the code for the ng-class:

```
 <div class="checkLabel checkbox handPointer" ng-click="test = !test">
     <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg" ng-init="test = false" ng-class="test ? 'fa-check-square-o' : 'fa-square-o'"></i>
     <label>test</label>
 </div>
```

When I load the page there is an http request that updates the test variable. If the test variable evaluates to false then there is no problem.  However if the test variable evaluates as true then both the 'fa-square-o' and 'fa-check-square-o' are applied to the html element's class.  I see this when I inspect the element on the browser.

```
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-square-o fa-check-square-o" ng-init="test = false" ng-class="test ? 'fa-check-square-o' : 'fa-square-o'"></i>
```

Angular HTTP Request

```
var promise = $http.getData("URL");
promise.then(function(result) {
     // use the result
     $scope.test = true;
}
```

One other note is that when I would click on the div it toggles the test variable (which does work).  Therefore when the page loads if the test variable evaluates to true then it will show the false picture (fa-square-o) because both classes will be applied and when I click on the div the first time it does not change the picture because it changes the variable to false and the ng-class is working correctly (showing the fa-square-o). Then when I click it a second time it changes test to be true and will show the correct picture (fa-check-square-o).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I have found a strange aspect of this bug.  This piece of code is contained within an angular directive and depending on a tab chosen this directive will be visible or not.  Assume for simplicity the code is on tab A and there is another tab B. The promise will be called when tab A is chosen.  When the page is refreshed on tab A this bug occurs.  When the page is refreshed on tab B, and then tab A is chosen, the correct images will be shown.  I hope I explained this well if not please feel free to ask for clarifications.

UPDATE:

I am not sure if this is exactly a solution, but I have gotten it to work my changing the initial value to true.  Like I said I do not know why this worked but when I changed it to start as true then the correct picture would show up on load and there would be no problems when clicking on the div.

Comment: What if test is initialized in controller rather than in html file?

Comment: @Sagar I am now initializing it in the controller but it still has the same problem thanks for the idea I thought it would work too.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been driving me insane. You're using the directive correctly. There must be some race condition bug in the directive.

I have fixed it using two different methods. I prefer #2.

1. Add a $timeout() to the promise callback where you set the value of the variable to be true on first load. The 1 second worked for me. It seems like a bit of a hack, though.

   ```
   .then(function(){
     $timeout(function(){
       $scope.test = true;
     }, 1000);
   }
   ```
2. Don't use the `ng-class` directive. Instead, use interpolation in the `class` attribute. This isn't against the Angular rules.

   ```
   class="fa fa-fw fa-lg {{ getSquareClass() }}"

   $scope.getSquareClass = function(){
     return $scope.test ? 'fa-square-check-o' : 'fa-square-o';
   };
   ```

P.S. I'm sure you've moved on with your life, so this is for anyone else who encounters this strange issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have the quotes wrong assuming you are not on a really old version of Angular.  What happens when you try:

```
 <div class="checkLabel checkbox handPointer" ng-click="test = !test">
     <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg" ng-init="test = false" ng-class="test ? 'fa-check-square-o' : 'fa-square-o'"></i>
     <label>test</label>
 </div>
```

if that doesn't work check this post out:  [AngularJS toggle class using ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397252/angularjs-toggle-class-using-ng-class)

Comment: ng-class="test" ? 'fa-check-square-o' : 'fa-square-o' ~ is this a valid syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg" ng-init="test=false" ng-class="{'fa-check-square-o': test, 'fa-square-o': !test}"></i>
```

Comment: I tried this and it has the same problem as before.