# How can I and an ng-Class conditional expression that evaluates a 2 way data bind value?

Tags: angularjs

I have a button that cycles through an array when clicked. When I reach the first indexed item in the array, I want to add a class called `lastButton`. In the html, when using `ng-class`, I can't seem to understand how to evaluate an expression that is derived from a 2 way data bind. Can anyone tell me if this is possible, or what's missing from my syntax?

```
<button type="button" class="left-btn col-xs-6" role="menuitem"
        ng-click="clickPrev()"
        ng-class="{lastButton : vm.xsDropdown.index  === 0}" >
  Previous
</button>
```

The vm object is derived from my controller that has the property xsDropdown.index

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15397408/3099132

Answer (score 0):

Is the below what you are looking for?

```
<button type="button" class="left-btn col-xs-6" role="menuitem" ng-click="clickPrev()"  
     ng-class="{'lastButton' : $first}">Previous</button>
```

`$first` refers to the first index of the ng-repeat ( I assumed the above `<button>` tag to be inside the `ng-repeat` element)