# Addclass dont work with angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, addclass

```
<form name="configurationForm" class="form-horizontal config-form" novalidate confirm-on-exit>
```

I have this code, if I add a class to the input and if I put a different value, the initial, it works for me but if I put: `input type = "number"` but if I put: `input type = "text"`, does not work

```
<input highlight type="text" maxlength="32" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,4})?$/" step="0.0001" class="form-control input-config" name="orifice_size" id="orifice_size" ng-max="model.asset.line_size"ng-model="model.asset.orifice_size"   >

module.directive('highlight', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: "="
        },
        link : function($scope, element, attributes, ctrl){
            $scope.$watch('ngModel', function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
                if (scope.$parent.copyModel !== undefined && scope.$parent.copyModel[element[0].id] !== undefined &&  (newVal !== scope.$parent.copyModel[element[0].id] )) {
                    element.addClass('input-change');
                     console.log(element)
                }
                else{
                    element.removeClass('input-change');
                }
            });
        }

      };
});
```

Comment: this is an issue with your `if` condition or you aren't showing us all the code. What is copyModel?. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Ronnie thanks for yor answer,                                                                 if the values are not equal, I add a class to the input,
the initial value, and the value that the user inserts

Comment: what would `copyModel` look like? So you are comparing two numbers?

Comment: @Ronnie it is for me to load data from a table, so I can get the original value, I need to compare the original number, the new number is entered in the field

Comment: I wrote a quick fiddle that is working. It is still an issue with your `IF` condition..but if you put anything other than 3 in the first input, your class is added https://jsfiddle.net/y29ofdpq/

Comment: @Ronnie perfect, works fina, thanks

Comment: @FERNANDOORTIZ - consider using ng-class

Comment: I agree with @AmirYahalom in fact, check out my question I asked awhile back using ng-class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397252/angularjs-toggle-class-using-ng-class It could give you some ideas

Comment: using ng-class https://jsfiddle.net/y29ofdpq/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `attributes.$addClass()` in place of `element.addClass()` inside of your `$scope.$watch()` method.

If you take a look at the AngularJS source for `[ng-class]`, for some reason they don't use `element.addClass()` and instead use this approach.

I can't quite explain why this works exactly, but I do know that it will solve this issue specifically.

For reference, here's the source to AngularJS's `[ng-class]`:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngClass.js