# Angularjs add class to body in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs SPA application which has English and Arabic languages. For RTL and LTR properties I am trying to add class to body html element in app.js as below.

```
 $scope.changeLanguage = function (lang) {
        $scope.lang = lang == 'de_AR' ? 'de_AR' : 'de_EN';
        var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#body'));
        myEl.addClass('rtl');
}
```

Using above code I am not able to add class. I can see below code in html(browser).

```
<body ng-controller="RoslpAppController" class="ng-scope">
```

May I know what is the correct way to add css classes using Angularjs?

Comment: you can use `ng-class` for this

Comment: You can refer https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/may/23/right-to-left-rtl-text-display-in-angular-and-aspnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for ternary check in ng class

```
<div ng-class="(lang === 'de_AR') ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'"></div>
```

This is for multiple cases in ng class for one condition

```
<div ng-class="{'de_AR':'rtl', 'de_EN':'ltr'}[lang]"></div>
```

**Code inside controller**

```
$scope.changeLanguage = function (lang) {
        $scope.lang = lang == 'de_AR' ? 'de_AR' : 'de_EN';
        var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#body'));
        myEl.addClass('rtl');
}
```

Comment: Thanks i have added this ng-class="(lang === 'de_AR') ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'" and html i can see <body ng-controller="RoslpAppController" ng-class="(lang === 'de_AR') ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'" class="ng-scope rtl">. Is this is correct?

Comment: Yes correct. ng-scope is default class added by angular

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for **[`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)** directive . if you have a scope variable $scope.rtl that drives what part of your content is displayed, you can use ng-class to add dynamic classes:

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-class="{'rtl'}">
```

[`DEMO`](http://plnkr.co/edit/9LCs5f?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan. How can i switch the classes? If the language is arabic then rtl and if the language is english the ltr. How can i do this?

Comment: add a ternary operator to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397252/angularjs-toggle-class-using-ng-class

Comment: I have added ng-class="{{dir}}" and from controller $scope.dir=ltr i have done. Is this is the correct way i am following?

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-class

```
<body ng-controller="RoslpAppController" ng-class="{'class1':lang == 'de_AR', 'class2': lang == 'de_EN'} ng-scope">
```

Comment: Thank you. I have added ng-class="{lang == 'de_AR':rtl,lang == 'de_EN': ltr}" and i got Syntax Error: Token '==' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 7 of the expression [{lang == 'de_AR':rtl,lang == 'de_EN': ltr}] starting at [== 'de_AR':rtl,lang == 'de_EN': ltr}]. May i know what will be the correct syntex?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#body'));
```

looks for an element with the id 'body'
if you want to acces the body, use:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('body'));
```