# Dynamic classes using ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

This is not a duplicate.

In the other post, they are just doing a ternary operation. I wanna changes classes within ng-repeat.

I have this piece of code with little bugs.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="server-id-list-container" class="panel-body col-md-12 scrollbar">
    <div class="server-id-list-element" ng-class="serverIdLength > 12 ? 'col-md-3' : 'col-md-2'" ng-repeat="server in selection.serverIds">
        <p class="alert alert-info">{{server.serverId}}<span ng-click="removeServerId($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**:

```
_.forEach($scope.selection.serverIds, function(a) {
    $scope.serverIdLength = a.serverId.length;
});
```

**Scope Object:**

```
[
    {
        "serverId": "loma1pwipdb2002",
        "serverName": "",
    },
    {
        "serverId": "shdmqprtp1",
        "serverName": "",
    }
]
```

When I enter "loma1pwipdb2002", the class becomes `col-md-3` and since I am using ng-repeat applies for all elements. I want the class to be applied only to serverIdLength > 12 and if its lesser than 12, `col-md-2` should get applied.

Please advice.

Comment: Duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397252/angularjs-toggle-class-using-ng-class). Please make more research before posting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS toggle class using ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397252/angularjs-toggle-class-using-ng-class)

Comment: Yes, this doesnt look like a duplicate. In the other post, they are just doing a ternary operation. I wanna changes classes within ng-repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it correct that you want to switch your class for each element of `selection.serverIds` list separately based on `serverId` string length? Need to know your `selection.serverIds`, is it your "Scope Object"? If yes, then I would do just

```
<div 
  class="server-id-list-element"
  ng-repeat="server in selection.serverIds"
  ng-class="server.serverId.length > 12 ? 'col-md-3' : 'col-md-2'"> ... </div>
```

The problem is that your `$scope.serverIdLength` is being calculated once for all the list. While you want to have a dynamic class based on each item specific property.

Let's continue discussion if I didn't understand the issue and the entry conditions.

Comment: Hi I have edited my question with some images. I guess you might get a better understanding of the issue I am facing.

Comment: @a2441918 So what's the solution? is it my answer? if no, I recommend update your question. I also recommend to change the title of the issue!

Answer (score 1):

the issue seems to lie here:

```
_.forEach($scope.selection.serverIds, function(a) {
    $scope.serverIdLength = a.serverId.length;
});
```

No matter what `$scope.serverIdLength` will always be set to the length of the last serverId. That because it's a global variable and there is only one instance of it. This is why all your classes match. They all reference the same variable.

Instead like @dhilt suggested ditch the controller code and acccess the length in the dom:

```
ng-class="server.serverId.length > 12 ? 'col-md-3' : 'col-md-2'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
ng-class="{'col-md-3':server.serverId.length > 12, 'col-md-2':server.serverId.length <= 12}"
```