# AngularJS, how to change fontawesome icon on click? (ng-click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to have a checkbox, so when you click on the default FontAwesome empty box (`fa-square-o`) it gets changed with this icon (`fa-check-square-o`).

How can I do that with AngularJS? I need to put a function in the controller and call it from `ng-click`? What would be the correct function?

I found what I need in Jquery but would love to just use angular for it:

```
$("#checkBoxOn").click(function(event) {
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-check-square-o');
```

If possible help me convert this in Angular!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS toggle class using ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397252/angularjs-toggle-class-using-ng-class)

Comment: how would I apply the code found in your link to my example?



`<button class="btn" ng-click="autoScroll = !autoScroll">
  <i ng-class="autoScroll ? 'icon-autoscroll' : 'icon-autoscroll-disabled'"></i>
</button>`

Comment: Your class is `fa-check-square-o`. I would assume you'd want your inverse to be a plain `square-o`.

Comment: `<i ng-class="toggle ? 'fa-check-square-o' : 'square-o'" ng-click="toggle = !toggle"></i>`

Comment: yes, I was about to post that I figure it out!!! I did exactly like that and it works! Quick question, the 2 icons have a small width difference, how can I space 2 icons inside a cell in a html table?  I tried &ensp but doesnt work! I would if possible keep them bot in the same cell (I know that if I create a second cell I can space them how much I want!)

Comment: What do you mean? I assume you meant `&nbsp;`.

Comment: In my answer I added a version using some different angular directives, if you wanted to just use unicode. Maybe that works for you?

Comment: Thank you gonna take a look, anyway I meant `&ensp;` but I suppose it does the same as `&nbsp;`, but actually I solved it by giving some padding to one of the 2 icons so I get some space between them!

Comment: Never knew `&ensp;` before :-)

Comment: I updated my answer based on your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two parts:

1. You need something that holds a boolean if something is checked. We can do that using an expression like this: `ng-click="toggle = !toggle"`. Basically, each time you click the element with that directive, toggle will become what it wasn't before.
2. You can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to set the class: `i ng-class="toggle ? 'fa-check-square-o' : 'square-o'"></i>`

Together, this might become something like:

```
<span ng-click="toggle = !toggle">
   <i ng-class="toggle ? 'fa-check-square-o' : 'square-o'"></i>
   Some text with the toggle here, that is also clickable.
</span>
```

Based on your other question, to hide another element based on this, you can add [ngHide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) to it:

```
<table ng-hide="toggle">
```

This question is similar to [AngularJS toggle class using ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397252/angularjs-toggle-class-using-ng-class), but that does not answer the toggling portion.

Just to make it more interesting, you could do something with unicode instead if you don't want the extra dependencies. This uses [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and [ngHide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide).

```
<span ng-click="toggle=!toggle">
  <span ng-show="toggle">&#9744;</span>
  <span ng-hide="toggle">&#9745;</span>
  Some text with the checkbox here
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked).

When you change the checkbox, apply your method:

```
ng-checked="MyMethod()"
```

The most easiest example:

```
input type='checkbox' ng-checked='MyMethod()' />
```

Script:

```
$scope.MyMethod = function() {
  //your logic
  return true; //checked
}
```

Comment: could you give me an example? I'm new to AngularJS, thank you

Comment: provided a simple example snippet.

Comment: thank you very much but I m gonna use the solution posted above which doesn't require scripts! thank you anyway

Comment: This is what I like about angular, a lot of solutions you can choose to solve one problems

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jQuery, use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass), to change the classes according to what a variable holds

```
<checkbox ng-click="value = !value">
<span class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-square-o': !value , 'fa-check-square-o': value}"></span>
```