# Jquery click function for toggle is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario,where footer must be collapsed based on device.Here,I used toggle class for collapse in mobile device,the toggle click is not working.

JavaScript code:

```
// Code goes here

$(function() {
  $('.footer-links-holder h3').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PCETstXeYzgIsnys8AKZ?p=preview)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write your JS like this -

```
$('.footer-links-holder h3').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
});
```

Your updated [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9NunO8NNKVaWl3Wep9CE?p=preview)

Comment: Is it possible to write toggle class with angularjs.

Comment: @pbsbr Yes, you can writte toggleClass with angularJS please visit [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397252/angularjs-toggle-class-using-ng-class) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Batter practice is write code in ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.footer-links-holder h3').click(function () {
     $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $('.footer-links-holder h3').off().click(function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```